# TSQL - less than or greater than date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to produce a query that shows if startdate is less than 4 months old give 5% if its older than 4 months give 10%.

I am using SQLFiddle and I not getting the right output. At the moment it’s giving me 5% on all the columns or if I replace

```
 SET Discount = ''
```

to

```
 SET Discount = '5%'
```

It will query successfully but does not show data.

This is the code I did...

```
Declare
 startdate  date,
 finishdate date,
 Discount varchar(4)

UPDATE Persons
SET [Discount] = ' ' 
SELECT *, DATEADD(MM,-4,startdate) AS TADate
FROM Persons 
WHERE Discount = '5%' AND startdate < dateadd(month,-4,getdate()) OR 
Discount = '10%' AND startdate < dateadd(month,4,getdate())
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case` statement in `update` to allocate discount based on `date`

Try `update` like this

```
UPDATE Persons SET [Discount] = case 
when startdate > dateadd(month,-4,getdate()) and startdate <= getdate() then '5%' 
when startdate < dateadd(month,-4,getdate()) Then '10%' 
End
SELECT * FROM Persons
```

Comment: Appericate you quick reply unfortunately all the columns for Discount is showing 5%.

Comment: @DiscoDude - Updated check now. `when startdate > dateadd(month,4,getdate()) then '10%'`

Comment: @DiscoDude - Can you share the `sqlfiddle` link

Comment: Apologies in SQLFiddle I have inserted records that are slightly different to what I have put here. - I have changed -4 to -2

Comment: @DiscoDude - what is the expected result in that fiddle can you add that in question. Am little unclear of requirement now

Comment: Regardless of finishdate. EmpID 1,2 and 3 it should show 5% and for EmpID 4 it should show 10%.

Comment: but all the startdate's are less than 4 months from now

Comment: @VAR46 - I checkout your sqlfiddle and I believe that is the output it should be. your are a superstar. Many Thanks

Comment: I thing you could use else.  I don't think they intended for exactly 4 months to get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, you can use case statement  when with update  statement as

```
 Declare
 startdate  date,
 finishdate date,
 Discount varchar(4)

UPDATE Persons
SET [Discount] = Case 
When startdate < dateadd(month,-4,getdate()) and startdate <= getdate()
Then '5%' when startdate < dateadd(month,4,getdate()) Then '10%'  
End
```

Comment: @Ajay- Appreciate you quick reply unfortunately all the columns for Discount is showing 5%.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be one of the solution for your problem

```
 Declare @Persons Table(
 startdate  date,
 finishdate date,
 Discount varchar(4))

 insert into @Persons(startdate,finishdate ) -- sample data
 Values('20150801','20150901'),('20151101',null),('20050101','20060101'),('20150821','20150901'),('20150821','20151001')

UPDATE @Persons
SET [Discount] = Case 
When startdate > dateadd(month,-4,getdate())Then '5%'
 else '10%'  
End

select * from @Persons
```