# how do I declare more than one SET

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Related to the previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380695/tsql-less-than-or-greater-than-date/34391446#34391446)

I would like help on how to declare more than on SET or CASE, if possible. I am using SQL Fiddle to test please see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/149f3/5)

```
{
 EmpID int,
 startdate  datetime,
 finishdate datetime,
 Discount varchar(4),
 SomeData varchar(4) 
}

UPDATE Persons SET [Discount] = case, [SomeData] = case 
when startdate > dateadd(month,-4,getdate()) and startdate <= getdate()  
then '5%' AND SomeData '<5' 
when startdate < dateadd(month,-4,getdate()) Then '10%' AND SomeData '>4' 
End
SELECT * FROM Persons
```

Thank you in advance if anyone can help me.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Could you describe it and provide desired output?

Comment: Wild guess. **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/794017/1/0)** Probably you don't want to update it every time so consider computed column or view instead.

Comment: @lad2025 - if from startdate to finishdate is less than 4 months then discount is 5% and SomeData column name shows <4. If from startdate to finishdate is more than 4 months then discount is 10% and SomeData column name shows >4. I will update the code because it is slightly different to what sql fiddle is written. Thank you

Comment: @lad2025 - don't understand what you mean. could you explain, please

Comment: getdate()  will change over time. So  difference between start and today may be 3 month and discount 5, but 2 months later difference will be 5 month and discount 10

Comment: @lad2025 - ok. that DEMO link you provided did you do anything?

Comment: No it does not do anything. I post it because I am bored. 

Comment: Are you trying for `UPDATE Persons SET [Discount] = case ... end, [SomeData] = case ... end WHERE ...`? The `case` expressions are separate and you will need to repeat the logic to set the various fields.

Comment: @DiscoDude please explain what you want to do *in the question itself*, not a demo link that may be gone tomorrow. What does "multiple SET" even mean? Why don't you execute multiple UPDATE statements with different filters? Almost certainly it will be faster than processing *all* rows in the table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I am going to delete this thread. I am finding it difficult what the customer are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You got a lot of syntax errors and probaly some logic ones.
I managed to write sothing runs but I doubt it fetches the results you are looking for.

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/149f3/16)

You main syntax/semantic problems are:

1. a CASE statement evaluates a set o boolean expressions and returns a (single) value.
2. that `someData '<4'` really don't makes sense (and raises a error since it's just a column name followed by a string literal with no operation between). Hard to tell what do you want here in special considering someData is a varchar(4).